# Can clearing DefaultRequestHeaders everytime on a static HttpClient cause issues in an Azure Function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a static HttpClient instance in an Azure Function app. I then add Auth headers on every request to the Http trigger.

I am currently doing this on every request

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
```

Then I add my other headers, could this cause issues? Or is it best practice to clear them before adding them in case they already exist?

Comment: What kind of trigger does the function use?

Comment: @PeterBons Http trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `DefaultRequestHeaders` of `HttpClient` if that instance is possibly shared by multiple invocations of the Azure Function and the value of the headers changes per request. In this scenario you should use the `Headers` property of the `HttpRequestMessage` class.

Using the `DefaultRequestHeaders` of `HttpClient` is problematic because multiple invocations can change the headers so you cannot rely on the httpclient sending the right header because another invocation of the function can have changed the headers in its own way.

Comment: The auth header will always be the only header required and it will always be the same , in which case is it safe to clear them? Or is that risky incase another thread comes in with them now cleared out? I suppose I could check for null

Comment: *Or is that risky incase another thread comes in with them now cleared out?* -> Yes, add them once or check if they have been added already or not